# Send byte data in the request

Tags: php, curl, byte

Hi I am having trouble sending only byte data in a request

I only want to sent the **[bytes from data stream]** but am struglling in stripping this from my curl request.

Can anybody help me stripping this of via curl please.

```
-----------------------------7dc1f42e3005a8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="file.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mpeg

**[bytes from data stream]**

-----------------------------7dc1f42e3005a8--
```

The curl that I am using below, I am wondering if there is a quick way in curl to send only a specific part of load in this case only the byte data.

```
$fp             = fopen($localfile['tmp_name'], 'r');
$ch             = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); // --data-binary
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.com/api/v4/track/upload?api_key=xxx&filetype=mp3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'));

$response   = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: Hi Chetan Ameta, yes I have looked at the example http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php#115160 however still have doubt is this the way to go or is there a more subtle quicker option?

Comment: see my answer.. hope this will help[ you

Answer (score 0):

you can use below solution

```
//your url
$url = 'http://localhost/test/test.php';

$file = realpath('php1.php');

// build multipart
//set appropriate content type in headers

$params  = "--ABC1234\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    . "--ABC1234\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: text/php\r\n"
    . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"php1.php\"\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . file_get_contents($file) . "\r\n"
    . "--ABC1234--";

$first_newline      = strpos($params, "\r\n");
$multipart_boundary = substr($params, 2, $first_newline - 2);
$request_headers    = array();
$request_headers[]  = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params);
$request_headers[]  = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $multipart_boundary;

// send the request now

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

on other end you will be able to get uploaded file in `$_FILES` variable.

Tested at local server.

Hope this will help you.